# Open VM Tools producing warnings in syslog every 30 seconds / how do I suppress these warnings?

Tags: vmware

I would like to adjust my question slightly as I just updated one of my servers from 12.04 to 12.04.1 and am now seeing the same warnings on the upgraded server as well, so I am suspecting there is something with the kernel (which was upgraded) or one of the other packages.

So since there appears to be a lack of 'resolution' (googled for a quite a while to find something), can someone tell me how to suppress the warnings for open-vm-tools.

---[ original question below]---

I setup a new server today (VMware guest) and noticed in the `/var/syslog` the following warning entries:

(coming from open-vm-tools)

```
Jan 29 19:20:49 mail01 vmsvc[1168]: [ warning] [guestinfo] Error sending GuestMemInfo.
Jan 29 19:20:49 mail01 vmsvc[1168]: [ warning] [guestinfo] Failed to send vmstats.
```

These warnings are happening every 30 seconds.  Oddly enough however VMware Infrastructure Client appears to be showing correct information regardless of the warnings.  I have several other servers all running Ubuntu 12.04 (some upgraded from 10.04 even) that are running `open-vm-tools`, and none of them are producing this warning.

I have googled the error message but have come up with nothing as of yet.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I do realize the alternative is to compile and install the tools directly from the server, but I would rather just use a package that has worked on other machines.

Host: VMware ESX Server 3i, 3.5.0, build 207095 (best I can do an HP Proliant DL580 G2)
Guest / OS: Ubuntu 12.04.1 - 32bit

Any other information that I can provide, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2261082#2261082) in the vmware forums, you have to modify `isolation.tools.setinfo.disable` to `false` in your vmx file:

```
[...]
isolation.tools.setinfo.disable = "false"
[...]
```

Further explanations:

> If you have this setting "isolation.tools.setinfo.disable = "true" this mean "Setinfo communication from tools to the ESXi host are being blocked".
>
> Refer this Link for more detail about this parameter  page 6  http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vi35_security_hardening_wp.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have since moved to a different platform due to some unsupported hardware changes, but I hope this answer will help someone else encountering the same notice messages.